# First error: common.exception.SfdcSqlException: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Tags: formula-field

I have created formula field named "Second Audit Required" as shown below :

```
IF(And(AND(Text(Status__c)='Closed',TEXT(ServiceStep__c)='Treatment',Order__r.Account_Name__r.Account_Types__r.Name='Individual'), AND(Sequence_No__c=1),And(Text(Service_Audit_Type__c) !='Second Audit')),
IF(Order_Service_Area__r.Service_Plan__r.SP_Code__c<>Null,
IF(AND(Order_Service_Area__r.Service_Plan__r.SP_Code__c="SP0875",TODAY()-
Delivery_Date__c>1460 ),True,
IF(AND(Order_Service_Area__r.Service_Plan__r.SP_Code__c="SP0573",TODAY()-Delivery_Date__c>180),True,
IF(AND(Order_Service_Area__r.Service_Plan__r.SP_Code__c="SP0726",TODAY()-Delivery_Date__c>180),True,
IF(AND(Order_Service_Area__r.Service_Plan__r.SP_Code__c="SP0070",TODAY()-Delivery_Date__c>365),True,
IF(AND(Order_Service_Area__r.Service_Plan__r.SP_Code__c="SP0634",TODAY()-Delivery_Date__c>730),True,
IF(AND(Order_Service_Area__r.Service_Plan__r.SP_Code__c="SP0577",TODAY()-Delivery_Date__c>180),True,
IF(AND(Order_Service_Area__r.Service_Plan__r.SP_Code__c="SP0072",TODAY()-Delivery_Date__c>180),True,
IF(AND(Order_Service_Area__r.Service_Plan__r.SP_Code__c="SP0469",TODAY()-Delivery_Date__c>1460),True,
IF(AND(Order_Service_Area__r.Service_Plan__r.SP_Code__c="SP0724",TODAY()-Delivery_Date__c>365),True,
IF(AND(Order_Service_Area__r.Service_Plan__r.SP_Code__c="SP0438",TODAY()-Delivery_Date__c>180),True,
IF(AND(Order_Service_Area__r.Service_Plan__r.SP_Code__c="SP0725",TODAY()-Delivery_Date__c>730),True,
IF(AND(Order_Service_Area__r.Service_Plan__r.SP_Code__c="SP0584",TODAY()-Delivery_Date__c>730),True,
IF(AND(Order_Service_Area__r.Service_Plan__r.SP_Code__c="SP0723",TODAY()-Delivery_Date__c>180),True,
IF(AND(Order_Service_Area__r.Service_Plan__r.SP_Code__c="SP0729",TODAY()-Delivery_Date__c>1460),True,
IF(AND(Order_Service_Area__r.Service_Plan__r.SP_Code__c="SP0067",TODAY()-Delivery_Date__c>180),True,
IF(AND(Order_Service_Area__r.Service_Plan__r.SP_Code__c="SP0443",TODAY()-Delivery_Date__c>1460),True,
IF(AND(Order_Service_Area__r.Service_Plan__r.SP_Code__c="SP0627",TODAY()-Delivery_Date__c>180),True,
IF(AND(Order_Service_Area__r.Service_Plan__r.SP_Code__c="SP0727",TODAY()-Delivery_Date__c>180),True,
IF(AND(Order_Service_Area__r.Service_Plan__r.SP_Code__c="SP0728",TODAY()-Delivery_Date__c>365),True,
False))))))))))))))))))),False),False)
```

When I am doing a query in batch class and using this field to retrieve and filter I am getting an error as below :

> First error: common.exception.SfdcSqlException: ORA-00920: invalid
>   relational operator

Query is :

```
[Select id,name from ObjectNAME__c where 
 Second_Audit_Required__c= true and Second_Audit_Required__c != null];
```

Comment: Best you also cut and paste the formula field formula into the question.

Comment: The field is too big and it is hitting text limit here that's why I have posted an image here.

Comment: Surprising as it doesn't look that long.

Answer (score 3):

The problem may be this Salesforce known issue [A formula field with a result of NULL causes SOQL retreival to fail](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001BuEQAU&title=a-formula-field-with-a-result-of-null-causes-soql-retreival-to-fail) as it includes the same exception and is about formula fields.

Until that is fixed, change your formula to never return null as described in the known issue:

> **Workaround**
> Ensure the formula result is TRUE or FALSE.

(Whether or not this is the correct answer, when you get an unexpected message it is usually worth cut and pasting - so it is an exact copy - the message into Google to see if others have come across it.)

Comment: I have checked that already on google but i did not find solution because i read that formula field which has return type as checkbox, the blank or null value is considered as false so why this formula is returning null value i can not understand the link is https://wdcigroup.net/salesforce-check-nullempty-value-of-a-field/

Comment: Because formula fields are not persisted on the database. They are much like Schrodinger’s cat: you can only know their result when you look at the field. So it doesn’t really matter that your formula is set to return blank or null, the error is inside of it, before the platform can return that value to your query.

Comment: I have changed the return type of formula field to text from checkbox and it is working as expected but I did not get the reason of error yet.